# JSF - scrolling datatable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I've used [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) BalusCs guide to view and paging datatables. It's very nice and useful guide (where would I be without it?), but I have one more question (maybe directly for you, BalusC):

Is there some posibility to scroll datatable horizontally and mainly vertically (without moving a headers)?

Thank you

**EMERGENCY SOLUTION** (using HTML):

place `<h:form>` to `<div id="scrolltable">`

and define scrolltable in css, for example:

```
#scrolltable{
  width: 920px; height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not directly possible in HTML and therefore also not with the standard set of JSF components. You would need to bring in a lot of specific CSS/JS works. That's too much of detail and pain to summarize in a single answer.

However, there exist 3rd party JSF component libraries which offers that in a single ready-to-use component. For example [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableScrolling.jsf) and [RichFaces 4.x](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&skin=blueSky) (and [RichFaces 3.x](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/scrollableDataTable.jsf)) have scrollable datatable components which are even able to fetch new rows by ajax. Since you tagged the question with `richfaces`, you should be able to use the RichFaces' one.

Comment: I've tagged it by richfaces, because I've heard somewhere on net, that richafaces can do it. It probably means I should explore richfaces little bit :] Thanks for tip, BalusC!